# i am facing issue with the react-query Devtools

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I am new to react-query, I am trying to fetch data from the post method on initial load, it works but react-query dev tools don't show my call. can anyone tell me what the issue is?
am I doing wrong something

```
const [snapshotData, setSnapShotData] = useState([]);

  const snapshotFunc = useCallback(async () => {
    const data = {
      L3: null,
      L4: null,
    };
    await axios
      .post("/dashboard/snapshot/", data)
      .then((res) => setSnapShotData(res.data));
  }, []);

  const {  isError, mutate } = useMutation(snapshotFunc, {
    retry: 3
  });
  

  useEffect(() => {
    mutate();
  }, [mutate]);
```

Comment: I think you have to return the axios response for react query to be able to be able to track its state

Answer (score 0):

The devtools only show queries, not mutations, as mutations are generally triggered imperatively.

What I'd like to point out is that you likely don't need the `snapshotData` local state, because react-query will return the state as the result of the mutation in the `data` field. Also, you don't have to wrap mutation functions in `useCallback`. But it is important that you *return* the result of the mutation:

```
const snapshotFunc = () => {
  const data = {
    L3: null,
    L4: null,
  };
  return axios.post("/dashboard/snapshot/", data)
};

const { data, isError, mutate } = useMutation(snapshotFunc, {
  retry: 3
});
  

useEffect(() => {
  mutate();
}, [mutate]);
```

Comment: i tried , that doesn't seems to work for me.

`const snapshotFunc = () => {
    const data = {
      L3: null,
      L4: null,
    };
    return axios.post("/dashboard/snapshot/", data)
  };

  const {  mutate, data:snapshotDataValue } = useMutation(snapshotFunc, {
    retry: 3
  });

  const snapshotData = snapshotDataValue.data

  console.log("data",snapshotData)
  

  useEffect(() => {
    mutate();
  }, [mutate]);`